# "with others" repetition

Tags: word-choice, repetition

I've created a sentence:

> It is proven that people are more happy when they can share their good moments with others, and that they easier overcome failures shared with others.

I suppose it doesn't look good, but I struggle to avoid the second "with others". Maybe:

> It is proven that people are more happy when they can share their good moments with others, and that they easier overcome shared failures.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not worry about style until you fix the grammatical errors: "easier" should be "more easily." Moreover, your second sentence is ambiguous and will likely be interpreted to mean something quite different from the first sentence. "Shared failures" **may** mean failures that are disclosed to others, but it also, and far more frequently, means failures that you and others had in common.

> Sharing experiences with others has been proven beneficial: it makes us even happier about good moments and lets us overcome failures more easily.